# In some mobiles I get the error navigator.storage.getDirectory() is not a function

Tags: google-chrome-storage

I'm using Origin Private File System inside a PWA, so it's served under HTTPS.

Mobiles are using Chrome version 115.

When the code tries to get the root directory `navigator.storage.getDirectory()` the error "getDirectory()" is logged in console.

It happens inside a WebWorker and also in DevTools console.

```
let root = null;

(async function () {
    root = await navigator.storage.getDirectory()
    postMessage('storage_ready');
})();
```

However, `navigator.storage.persistence()` returns true and `navigator.storage.estimate()` returns data. So **the object StoreManager is returned by navigator but seems to be somehow incomplete**.

I have tried to figure out the reason, why to return an object which affirms that it has persistence but it doesn´t have the method to access to the virtual file system ...

I have checked Chrome configuration, privacy configuration, PWA as App configuration, ... but I don´t find a clue.

It happend with version 114 and after updated Chrome worked but minutes later failed again.

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was happening?

Comment: No, I never find out the reason, sorry.

I changed the storage of the blobs to IndexDB and abandoned OPFS.

So far, it's working much much better.

Not so comfy but more reliable.

All mobiles were same brand, model and browser so I thought it was going to be really really difficult to resolve.